# Is the expression "Say your piece" or "Say your peace"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I have googled this one and seen arguments for both sides.

*Say your piece* would imply that you've had the opportunity to make your part of the statement on the subject.

*Say your peace* would imply that you've had the opportunity to speak and set your mind at ease.

Clearly, they both make perfect sense in those contexts.  To be clear, I want to know which is the form used by most people?

Comment: Why should only one of them make sense? "Clearly, they both make perfect sense in those contexts." Isn't that the answer?

Comment: This is a non-question (NARQ).

Comment: @Kris I don't disagree.  But, I've been yelled at before for saying my *peace*.  I want to see what is the According to Hoyle on this one . . .

Comment: Perhaps you meant "say your prayers" :)

Comment: Must have said *peace* when you should have said *piece*. There's Green Peace and then there are green peas.

Comment: @itsols Not even once . . .

Comment: @Kris In what manner is this not a real question?  I would like you to justify that!

Comment: http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/12/piece-work.html

Comment: @Kris So, you mark my question as not a real question, then go ahead and find the answer?  That's just dirty pool.

Comment: lol! "Interestingly, 'piece' was sometimes spelled 'peace' in the 16th and 17th centuries. A 1523 act issued by Henry VIII, for example, referred to 'every peace of Worstede.'"

Comment: @Susan Sh... I was expecting David to discover that.

Comment: ...and of course, there's the obvious.  If you *say* "say your piece (peace)!", no one will know which piece or peace you meant! ;-)  The idiom that is familiar to me is "Speak your piece (peace)", not "say your piece (peace)."

Comment: According to the OED it is "to say (also speak) one's piece".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be *say your piece* and *hold your peace*. Because 'peace' and 'piece' are [homophones](http://grammar.about.com/od/alightersideofwriting/a/peacegloss.htm), they are easily confused.

Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=say+your+piece%2C+say+your+peace&year_start=1800&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csay%20your%20piece%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20your%20peace%3B%2Cc0) shows *piece* being 20X more common than *peace* in 2008, but 45X more common in 1999 (acknowledging the horrendous predictive value of Ngrams). So, in a decade or so... it may well be; not based on the Ngram, but based on how misuse has so often turned into common usage.

Comment: I guess the question comes down to:  Has *say your peace* become a proper usage due to continued confusion?  It certainly makes sense in the context I've listed above.

Comment: And then there's "*Drop your piece* and come out with your hands up!"

Answer (score 2):

I have always seen "say your piece," as if telling an actor to recite their script.

Other than that, I found that "speak your peace" can be used, but only in a very limited context, where "peace" literally means "peace."  The general form uses "piece."  This article also mentions that "speak your peace" is usually used as a variant of "hold your peace."

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_it_speak_your_piece_or_speak_your_peace#slide=01&article=Is_it_speak_your_piece_or_speak_your_peace

Comment: Can you find a citation for that usage?

Comment: Personal experience? Other than that I have to citation.

Comment: I've found some usages saying that you will recite the statements or lines you've prepared.  This doesn't necessarily conflict with the usage I stated above, though.  Saying your piece can easily mean saying the things you intend to say before you stop talking about the subject.

Comment: @DavidM Edited with a source.

Comment: Thanks.  I want to hold off accepting the answer until I see some more comments.

Comment: @DavidM Sure.  I would like to learn more too.

Comment: BTW - It is not a variant of hold your peace, but rather the opposite.  Holding your peace is staying silent.  Saying your peace would be speaking your mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am only familiar with 'speak your piece' in the sense of 'I gave him a piece of my mind', or 'a piece of advice'.

I have never encountered the 'peace' spelling outside a church context, when in the ritual of 'pax vobiscum' people *exchange* a sign of peace. Perhaps the 'peace' example here could be a mutilated reference to this, otherwise I fail to see how you can *say* you 'peace of mind', although you can definitely seek, and attain it, as well as 'get something off your chest to have some peace of mind'.

Furthermore, looking at the source link in the answer above, it's full of inconsistencies and errors - 'peace' is confused with 'piece' in the first answer slide, which doesn't help matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "piece" as "your thoughts on the subject" or perhaps, just "your thoughts". Except in a religious or quasi-religious context I can't conjour up any instance where "say your peace" would really make much sense. Perhaps after "saying your piece" you would attain peace of mind, but that's as close as I can get.